# How to get mat select selected value in tool tip using angular material

Tags: angular, tooltip, angular-material, angular5

I am displaying a drop down using angular material mat select. I want to display selected element using material tool tip.

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="emp" [(value)]="selected" matTooltip="{{selected}} 
(openedChange)="oChange($event)" placeholder="Employee" [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
<mat-option  *ngFor="let p of emp" [value]="p" >{{p.name}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

But its showing [object object]

Here is content of emp

```
emp[
{"id":0101,"name":"damshad"},
{"id":0102,"name":"ranjan"},
{"id":0103,"name":"himanshu"},
{"id":0104,"name":"gourge"},
{"id":0105,"name":"taffic"},
{"id":0106,"name":"ajir"},
{"id":0107,"name":"mallom"}
]
```

Please help

Comment: can you post the content of emp?

Comment: I have updated the question with content of emp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You missed `{{}}` close curly braces.

I have create demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-table-delete-record-emnkfr?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html)

> Html code

```
 <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selected" matTooltip="{{getToolTipDEata(selected)}}"  multiple>
    <mat-option  *ngFor="let p of emp" [value]="p" >{{p.name}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

> ts code

```
selected=null;
  emp=[{
    name:'emp 1'
  },{
    name:'emp 2'
  }]

  getToolTipDEata(data){
    if(data && data.length){
      let msg="";
      data.forEach(res=>{
        msg+=res.name + " ";
      })
      return msg;
    }else{
      return "please select employee";
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it its not giving any value, means not displaying any thing. any better way to do this

Answer (score 7):

If you simply want to get what's displayed on the mat-select "trigger" in tooltip, use `triggerValue`:

```
<mat-select #matSelect [matTooltip]="matSelect.triggerValue">
</mat-select>
```

works with ngModel, reactive forms and multiple selection

Answer (score 5):

You can simple pass ngModel to Tooltip, Also you can change position with matTootipPosition.

```
  <mat-select 
    [(ngModel)]="emp" 
    matTooltip="{{emp}} 
    matTooltipPosition='above|below|left|right'
    >
    <mat-option  *ngFor="let p of emp" [value]="p" >{{p.name}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

Answer (score 2):

to display tooltip based on selected value you have to define id for mat-select element, than you can refer to its 'selected' property

```
<mat-select #testid [matTooltip]="testid .selected?.viewValue"
            (openedChange)="oChange($event)" placeholder="Employee" 
            [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
                <mat-option  *ngFor="let p of emp" [value]="p" >{{p.name}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Answer (score 1):

original code

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="emp" [(value)]="selected" matTooltip="{{selected}} 
(openedChange)="oChange($event)" placeholder="Employee" [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
<mat-option  *ngFor="let p of emp" [value]="p" >{{p.name}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

my code

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="emp" [(value)]="selected" matTooltip="{{toppings.value.name}} 
(openedChange)="oChange($event)" placeholder="Employee" [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
<mat-option  *ngFor="let p of emp" [value]="p" >{{p.name}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed `}` in this `matTooltip="{{selected}`

Comment: I updated it, but still facing same issue, if i try {{selected.name}} its not displaying any thing. Any better way to do this.